# What is the difference between referencing to a label with or without the tilde?

Tags: cross-referencing

What is the difference between referencing to a label with or without the tilde? I do not see any difference. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You will see the difference if Section is the last word of line and the number goes to next line. If you want to keep then  together with a space in between `~` puts an unbreakable space and they behave as a single word.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Now it is clear.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.